# Ansible "msg": "Failed to find required executable pvs"

Tags: ansible-2.x

I'm using the following in Ansible 2.1 on OSX and getting the subject message:

lvg: vg=vgname pvs=pvname state=present

Bug? or what am I doing wrong.

This syntax was working OK with ansible 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to ensure that the lvm packages are installed on your target system.
So add to your Ansible playbook something like this:

```
tasks:
  - yum:
      name: 'lvm*'
      state: present
```

Answer (score 0):

On Centos or Redha,
You can use:
`sudo yum makecache`
`sudo yum install lvm` if not found use
`sudo yum install lvm2`

Thanks